# How can I add transactional safety to Javascript DML operations?

Tags: javascript, ajax-toolkit, rollback, savepoint

I am using `connection.js` and `apex.js` to add DML operations to a custom VisualForce page with `sforce.connection`.

There are actions in the page that can make multiple calls that will alter data. I'd like to add transactional safety to these actions, so that if a single statement fails, then all the previous statements within the transaction will be rolled back.

I know this is easy enough with Apex eg:

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

// Do something...

// Rollback if required
Database.rollback(sp);
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to do this when using the `sforce` javascript object.

Comment: No references to `Savepoint` in the [documentation or glossary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/glossary_ajax.htm?search_text=savepoint).

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find anything in the docs either, which is why I optimistically turned to here. I was wondering if it was called something else, or was maybe poorly documented.  I also checked the `sforce` object itself and couldn't see anything in there that looked like it would do this.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you face here is that each operation is a self-contained transaction. So you don't have the same options available to you. If you want to use transaction control, you need to use `Apex` so that all of your operations are, in fact, wrapped in one transaction.

The documentation on the AJAX Toolkit is completely devoid of any reference to `Savepoint`.

Comment: This is probably the most regrettable part about the APIs. SOAP, REST, and Bulk all suffer from this design flaw.